# Automatic imports in Gradle plugin

Tags: plugins, gradle, customization

I have created a Gradle plugin that has several custom task types. In order to use those task types in the build I need to explicitly import them. Is there a way to import those task classes automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, adding implicit imports isn't a public feature at this time. What you can do is to provide a plugin that covers the main use cases so that it's rarely necessary to declare tasks explicitly.

Comment: I was afraid of that :)!

Comment: Of course there are also hacks (use default package, make task `Class` instance available as top-level property), but I don't recommend to go there.

Comment: In fact, I tried adding Class instance properties, but it failed with exception upon plugin applying,