# How to ignore explicitly importing classes like gradle kotlin script when writing custom kotlin-dsl

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

In the gradle's kotlin build script, we don't need explicitly import classes or functions like `plugins`, `repositories` or `dependencies` in build script **build.gradle.kts**.

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.10"
    val springBootVersion = "2.1.0.RELEASE"
    val detektVersion = "1.0.0-RC10"

    id("org.springframework.boot") version springBootVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version detektVersion
}


repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/s1m0nw1/KtsRunner"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("cn.pilipa:pilipa-spring-boot-starter-logging:2.0.10")

    implementation("de.swirtz:ktsRunner:0.0.5")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"){
        exclude(module = "junit")
    }
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testCompile("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:${kotlinTestVersion}")
    testCompile("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:${kotlinTestVersion}")

    detektPlugins("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:${detektVersion}")
}
```

How to implement this similar feature in the custom kotlin-dsl script to implicitly import classes in kotlin-dsl script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle defines a list of implicit imports that has no mechanism for extending this list.  This is the same as for `build.gradle` and Groovy versions as it is for the Kotlin versions.

See also: [Automatic imports in Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984034/automatic-imports-in-gradle-plugin)

Which still holds true as of today.  There is a TODO remaining in the Kotlin Gradle Script [source code](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/9d4f2465571b3b8c30a3009951a85824018ca36f/subprojects/provider/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/support/ImplicitImports.kt#L39) (*master branch as-of Nov 22, 2018*) related to this:

> // TODO: let this be contributed by :plugins

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. It's a bit difference with what I asked. The question is not relative to writing gradle kotlin dsl script. I would like to implicitly import classes for self-created kotlin dsl. Looks like gradle is good example as reference for how to implicitly importing classes in kotlin dsl script.

Comment: You just want Kotlin-script implied imports?  That is supported by Kotlin script and is documented.  "Kotlin-dsl script" isn't something that exists, other than the Kotlin DSL for Gradle (using that terminology).  So you want any Kotlin Script to have implied imports?

Comment: Yes. I'm creating my own dsl script not writing gradle script. I would like to implicitly imports in my dsl script.